# How do texture coordinated get normalized in GLSL

Tags: textures, glsl, coordinates

So I know each vertex's texCoords get normalized to a value between 0.0f and 1.0f upon being sent to a shader, but how does it determine whether a texCoord of 500, for instance, will be 0.7 or 0.1? What about if the object is drawn without specifying any texture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I know each vertex's texCoords get normalized to a value between 0.0f and 1.0f upon being sent to a shader

## This is not entirely accurate.

#### There are two reasons texture coordinates might wind up "normalized."

1. Actual normalization of fixed-point vertex attributes

   - (*e.g.* `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` values are cast to `GLfloat` and divided by **255.0f** (max value of data type))
2. Texture wrap mode

---

It sounds to me like **(2)** is what is doing the normalization here.

Say you have a `texCoord` of **500.0** and normalization as defined in **(1)** is not enabled. That value is out-of-normalized-range, so texture wrap comes into play. It may be:

1. #### Clamped

   - ```c
     TexCoord = clamp (TexCoord, 0.0, 1.0);                             {clamp}

                                        @@@ This is deprecated

                                     [500.0 --> 1.00]
     ```
   - **OR**
   - ```c
     TexCoord = clamp (TexCoord, 0.0 + 0.5/texSize, 1.0 - 0.5/texSize);
                                                                        {clamp to edge}

                                     [500.0 --> 1.0 - 0.5/texSize]
     ```
2. #### Repeated

   ```c
   TexCoord = fract (TexCoord);         [500.0 --> 0.00]
   ```
3. #### Mirrored

   ```c
   vec2 tc  = fract (TexCoord * 0.5f) * 2.0f;
   vec2 len = vec2 (1.0f, 1.0f);

   TexCoord = len - abs (tc - len);     [500.0 --> 0.00]
   ```
4. #### ...

Basically you can see that any value outside the range **[0.0, 1.0]** when using regular samplers and `texture (...)` will be brought back into range based on the wrap mode. I did not go through the entire list of modes, because there are dozens of extensions and this gives you a general idea.

---

You generally sample textures from the fragment shader though. Vertex normalization only happens when you call `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` with the **normalization** parameter set to `GL_TRUE`. Without attribute normalization enabled, attributes outside the normalized range will remain so and the fragment shader will receive interpolated values (also out-of-range). This is when texture wrap mode comes into play; unnormalized coordinates made it into the fragment shader and `texture (...)` uses the wrap mode to sort that all out.

It is possible to sample textures without using normalized texture coordinates, this is done using `texelFetch (...)`. But you give up a lot of luxuries like mipmapping and texture filtering in general.